# how to do the earth position animation with auto camera tracking

Tags: camera, animation-nodes, csv

let's say I have a .csv file with format as follow:
[image]

I have created the earth:

I want to do with Blender:

a.the longitude and latitude show as a sphere's position

b.the mag be as the sphere's radius

c.camera automatically tracking the sphere's position

It would be really grateful for any insight shared on this.

Comment: Please only one question per post, make as many posts as necessary. Please edit your post and reduce it to only (c) ***or*** (d) ***or*** (e).

Comment: Hi. Only point "e" is Blender related, other points seem to be about advanced formatting & presentation which Blender is not for. You may as well delete them.

Comment: @JadeLin Perhaps a sketch or render with some more information would help.